# Does Okta send group membership removal when user is assigned to app via a group?

Tags: okta, scim

### Setup:

- Group in Okta that has a user added
- SCIM app in Okta that has the group assigned and pushed

In the above setup, when we remove the user from the group, we don't receive a SCIM PATCH request to remove the user from the group.

When the user is directly assigned to the SCIM app, rather than through the group, we do see a remove SCIM patch request.

### Steps to replicate the issue:

1. Create a SCIM app in Okta and connect it to an application to receive SCIM update events.
2. Create a group in Okta and assign a user to that group.
3. Assign the group you created to the SCIM app in Okta, and push that group as well.
4. In Okta, remove the user from the group.
5. No remove SCIM operation is sent, which is what I would expect.

For the above steps, if you assign the user directly to the SCIM app, instead of via the group, the remove SCIM operation is sent. This is what we're looking for:

```
{
    "schemas": [
        "urn:ietf:params:scim:api:messages:2.0:PatchOp"
    ],
    "Operations": [
        {
            "op": "remove",
            "path": "members[value eq \"directory_user_01FFR215H3C9X6V5C8AJFKZ823\"]"
        }
    ]
}
```

One potential workaround is to manually push the groups from Okta, which sends a replace operation to re-set the group membership.

Is this expected behavior or is this a bug? Requiring assignment of thousands of users individually and not through groups is a blocker in some cases. However, we’re not receiving the correct group removal events if the users are assigned to the SCIM app via groups. Has anyone set up Okta SCIM with group assignments and receives the correct group membership removals?

Answer (score 1):

When user is removed from the group, Okta sends the request which "Disables" the user on the application but does not send the "delete" it.

So, what you are seeing is the right behaviour wrt of Okta user-group relation when it comes to SCIM provisioning.